# Python and CSV: Reading JSON from CSV

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a function that reads from a CSV file and dumps the contents to a file of choice. The contents of this csv file is a column where each rows contains a series of JSON objects like this(validated with jsonlint):

```
 [{"className": "Merchant", "__type": "Pointer", "objectId": "S8IGOwBn8Y"}, {"className": "Merchant", "__type": "Pointer", "objectId": "psNnxwFVmv"}, {"className": "Merchant", "__type": "Pointer", "objectId": "IHcC9ikKBJ"}, {"className": "Merchant", "__type": "Pointer", "objectId": "RVprbh5nWx"}, {"className": "Merchant", "__type": "Pointer", "objectId": "47Zjn9RRov"}, {"className": "Merchant", "__type": "Pointer", "objectId": "CoGtlmGzyo"}, {"className": "Merchant", "__type": "Pointer", "objectId": "yJHn9dBCIT"}, {"className": "Merchant", "__type": "Pointer", "objectId": "nEOY9RPRD4"}]
```

To conceptualize this a bit, this is what I want:

```
csv file ---> function that I wrote ---> something.json
```

In this case I used test.csv as input and test.txt as the output. It seems to work fine for the first json stream, but there is a quirk:

The first JSON object come out just fine:

```
[

{"className": "Merchant", "__type": "Pointer", "objectId": "S8IGOwBn8Y"}, 
{"className": "Merchant", "__type": "Pointer", "objectId": "psNnxwFVmv"}, 
{"className": "Merchant", "__type": "Pointer", "objectId": "IHcC9ikKBJ"}],
```

But after that, they start coming out like this:

```
"[{""className"": ""Merchant"", ""__type"": ""Pointer"", ""objectId"": ""S8IGOwBn8Y""}, 
{""className"": ""Merchant"", ""__type"": ""Pointer"", ""objectId"":  ""psNnxwFVmv""}, 
{""className"": ""Merchant"", ""__type"": ""Pointer"", ""objectId"": ""IHcC9ikKBJ""}, 
{""className"": ""Merchant"", ""__type"": ""Pointer"", ""objectId"": ""RVprbh5nWx""}, 
{""className"": ""Merchant"", ""__type"": ""Pointer"", ""objectId"": ""47Zjn9RRov""}, 
{""className"": ""Merchant"", ""__type"": ""Pointer"", ""objectId"": ""CoGtlmGzyo""}, 
{""className"": ""Merchant"", ""__type"": ""Pointer"", ""objectId"": ""yJHn9dBCIT""}, 
 {""className"": ""Merchant"", ""__type"": ""Pointer"", ""objectId"": ""nEOY9RPRD4""}', 
'\n[{""className"": ""Merchant"", ""__type"": ""Pointer"", ""objectId"": ""tNgLB9dobR""},
```

Here is the function that does this:

```
def read_csv(thefile):

    f = open('test.txt','w')
    with open(thefile, 'rb') as csvfile:

        #based on python documentation
        spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=']')
        for row in spamreader:
            f.write(str(row))

    f.close()
```

Two questions:

1. How do I ensure that the output is consistent? In other words, how can I eliminate the ""'s and the newline characters so that all the JSON is valid? Does it have to do with the nlsparams i'm adding?
2. Eventually, I don't want to dump to a .txt file, but to a .json file. How can this be done?

Thanks for any and all responses!

Comment: not getting.. means you have CSV file and you create JSON file. ?

Comment: I don't create the .json file. The .json file is already created but it is empty. I have a csv file, where each row is a series of JSON objects, starting with [ and ending with ]. The idea is that I want to read from this csv file(row by row) and pass these values to a .json file. The problem is that after the first row is read, other subsequent rows are read incorrectly.

Comment: It seems your first file is just json. Can you try to `import json` and `json.loads(your_file)` after having read it (in your code that would be `json.loads(csvfile.read())` instead of using `csv.reader()`)?

Comment: Why would you read your file as a csv file if there is only one column? Why not use the json module?

Comment: yes, use json module

Answer (score 0):

My guess -untested- :

```
import json
with open('test.txt','r') as input_file:
    with open('output.json','wb') as output_file:
        for row in input_file.readlines():
            output_file.write(json.loads(row))
```

In any case, using this lib will help you a lot: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html